# Not receiving FCM notifications send by PHP script

Tags: php, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I a trying to send FCM notifications from a PHP file to an Android app.

The app receives a test message send from Firebase Cloud Messaging console.

This is my FirebaseMessagingService class:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {


    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String s) {
        Log.e("NEW_TOKEN", s);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        Map<String, String> params = remoteMessage.getData();
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(params);
        Log.e("JSON_OBJECT", object.toString());

        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "Nilesh_channel";

        long pattern[] = {0, 1000, 500, 1000};

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "Your Notifications",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

            notificationChannel.setDescription("");
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(pattern);
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }

        // to diaplay notification in DND Mode
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = mNotificationManager.getNotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
            channel.canBypassDnd();
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);

        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent))
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setAutoCancel(true);


        mNotificationManager.notify(1000, notificationBuilder.build());


    }
}
```

And this is the services part in Android Manifest:

```
  <service
            android:name=".activity.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:stopWithTask="false">
            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

As PHP part I am using following script:

```
<?php
define('API_ACCESS_KEY','AAAAEX76PIM:...');
 $fcmUrl = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
 $token='e31H8qQq3ts:APA..';

     $notification = [
            'title' =>'title',
            'body' => 'body of message.',
            'icon' =>'myIcon', 
            'sound' => 'mySound'
        ];
        $extraNotificationData = ["message" => $notification,"moredata" =>'dd'];

        $fcmNotification = [
            //'registration_ids' => $tokenList, //multple token array
            'to'        => $token, //single token
            'notification' => $notification,
            'data' => $extraNotificationData
        ];

        $headers = [
            'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        ];


        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$fcmUrl);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fcmNotification));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
```

API Key and token are checked and right.

Please take a look at my code and tell me if am I doing something wrong.

The fact is that the app doesn't receive any FCM notification from the PHP script but from FCM console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of one way where a notification could not be delivered, which is when the token is incorrect.

When the Android Application registers itself with Firebase, a token is generated.
This token is then used by backend servers(In this case, your PHP script) to deliver push notifications.

Since you have verified that the token is proper,you print out $result to the console output.

This could provide us with clues on what is happening.

Comment: I have checked the value for $result and it has given me the clue. The token has changed for the app user. Thank you